# Resizing a PropertyGrid control

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have written code that will resize a Control and all of its controls, but there's a problem with the PropertyGrid. The user interface is a GroupBox that contains the TabControl tabContAll. In tabContAll is a TabPage that contains a PropertyGrid.

```
private void ResizeUI () 
{
    ui.Location = new Point (this.ClientRectangle.Left, this.ClientRectangle.Top + menubar.Height);
    ui.Size = new Size (this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - menubar.Height);
    ResizeControl (tabContAll, ui);
}

private void ResizeControl (Control control, Control parent) 
{
    control.Location = new Point (parent.ClientRectangle.Left, parent.ClientRectangle.Top);
    control.Size = new Size (parent.ClientRectangle.Width, parent.ClientRectangle.Height);

    foreach (Control child in control.Controls) {
        ResizeControl (child, control);
    }
}
```

This function is called when the form loads, and this is [what it looks like](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/unledjta.jpg/) compared to if I commented out the resizing in the loop so the PropertyGrid doesn't get resized:

[image]

[image]

Furthermore when it is resized, the description doesn't work. It just shows the name of the property.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it looks like your problem can be resolved without additional coding just using `Docking` and `Anchoring` of the winforms controls

Comment: +1. It looks like you want a DockPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to not write code for controls resizing unless you need a very very custom behaviour.

Set [`Control.Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) or [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties instead, and leave the rest to them.

For example, your case can be solved easily by setting the `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill` for both your `TabControl` and `PropertyGrid` (and obviously removing the custom resizing  methods).

Here's a complete MSDN Walkthrough for WinForms custom controls design:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

Comment: I didn't know there was such a property, I didn't really take any time to check out all the properties of controls. Guess I learned my lesson.